# How to get boolean value from a JAXB ajav object using jxpath?

Tags: java, jxpath

I am using spring 4.1.1 and JXpath 1.3.
I am able to read all the values from an JAXB java object using JXPath query except boolean values.

Do I need to follow any specific instructions to read boolean using JXpath?

Comment: what you mean by "JAXB object"? `JAXB` in JDK has only static methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html

Comment: I generated JaxB classes for the schema.Next connected to databse queried the xml message and built Java object using the JaxB classes

Comment: I found the root cause for this issue. In my JAXB class the return type defined as Boolean object. I changed it as primitive type boolean and it worked.